# Only one web app instance seems to be running

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

We have some timeouts issues with our Azure Web App with 3 instances.
I started debugging using the live stream metrics, and I see something really weird with the CPU usage:

[image]

Can someone explain why only one instance seems to be running?
We suspected the Affinity setting, so we disabled that, no luck.

Restarting that specific instance didn't help neither.

Comment: is this real live usage or load testing?

Comment: @BrunoFaria this from AppInsight againt our production site, no load testing.